# What is the difference between 255.255.255.255 and local broadcast IP?

Tags: sockets, networking, broadcast, winsock2

I've created a server that listens for broadcast messages from a client that sends them. My local address looks like `192.168.88.***`. I tested two cases: clients that send broadcast messages to `192.168.88.255` and `255.255.255.255`, but there wasn't any difference.

So, what is the difference between them, and when to use each of them?

Comment: 255.255.255.255. It is the broadcast address of the zero network or 0.0.0.0, which in Internet Protocol standards stands for this network, i.e. the local network.

Comment: See [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/37573/8499).

Answer (score 3):

`255.255.255.255` broadcasts to all subnets. Though most routers don't broadcast across subnets by default, you usually need to enable that capability.

`192.168.88.255` broadcasts only to the `192.168.88.xxx` subnet specifically.

Answer (score 0):

IP addresses are split into a network prefix (the top bits) and host (the bottom bits). Assuming `192.168.88.***` is `192.168.88.0/24` (a network mask of `255.255.255.0`), the low order 8 bits can hold 255 network addresses from `192.168.88.0` to `192.168.88.254`, and the local broadcast address `192.168.88.255`.

But you need to have specific knowledge about the subnet to write this broadcast address. For instance, `192.168.88/23` would have a broadcast address of `192.168.89.255`.

`255.255.255.255` is just an alias to the local broadcast address just as `0.0.0.0` is an alias to the local network. They can both be used generically without any special configuration. That's the difference. You really wouldn't bother using `192.168.88.255` because you'd also need a facility to configure that value. Why bother?